# How to plot time at night with an axis ranging from 20 (8 pm) to 12 (am) python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the time of the day I went to bed each day.

I was wondering if there exists an elegant solution to have my y-axis (time of the day) go from 20 h (or 10 PM) to 12 h or (12 PM)

Essentially, my ticks would be [20, 21, 22, 23, 00, 01, 02, ..., 09, 10, 11, 12]

Here is a part of my database :

| Date | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-09-21 | 23:26:01 | 05:40:01 |
| 2019-09-22 | 22:45:42 | 05:58:04 |
| 2019-09-23 | 22:56:40 | 05:55:23 |
| 2019-09-24 | 22:35:47 | 06:05:07 |
| 2019-09-25 | 00:23:13 | 06:03:08 |

Here is what I'd like to do :

[image]

And here's what I tried :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates as mdates

data = pd.read_csv("sleepdata.csv", sep=";")

plt.plot(mdates.date2num(data.Date), mdates.datestr2num(data.Start))
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have data stored in a `csv` file which can be read with pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'data/data.csv')
```

```
         Date     Start       End
0  2019-09-21  23:26:01  05:40:01
1  2019-09-22  22:45:42  05:58:04
2  2019-09-23  22:56:40  05:55:23
3  2019-09-24  22:35:47  06:05:07
4  2019-09-25  00:23:13  06:03:08
```

First of all you have to make some changes to the dataframe.
On y axis you want time from two different days: the evening of the day when you start sleeping and the morning of the next day. However `'Start'` and `'End'` columns don't contain info regarding date, only time.
Moreover, you want to plot time of different days. So, if I derive the date from `'Date'` column, on y axis you will have data from `2019-09-21 20:00:00` to `2019-09-25 12:00:00` (or the last date in your data) and you won't be able to compare time only, because each time belongs to different day. So you have to impute a date to `'Start'` and `'End'` columns and you have to chose always the same date, in order to be able to compare time only, regardless of the date. This is the reason why I impute the dates `2000-01-01` or `2000-01-02` to `'Start'` and `'End'` columns through `start` and `end` functions.
Then you have to convert `'Date'` column type from `str` to `datetime`.
At this point you have this dataframe:

```
        Date               Start                 End
0 2019-09-21 2000-01-01 23:26:01 2000-01-02 05:40:01
1 2019-09-22 2000-01-01 22:45:42 2000-01-02 05:58:04
2 2019-09-23 2000-01-01 22:56:40 2000-01-02 05:55:23
3 2019-09-24 2000-01-01 22:35:47 2000-01-02 06:05:07
4 2019-09-25 2000-01-02 00:23:13 2000-01-02 06:03:08
```

Pay attention to the date of `'Start'` and `'End'` columns: if `'Start'` hour is later than midday, they you have gone to bed the 1<sup>st</sup> day, on `2000-01-01`, otherwise the next day, on `2000-01-02`. In any case you always wake up on the 2<sup>nd</sup> day, on `2000-01-02`.
Now you can plot the dataframe day by day. I use a `df.iterrows` loop, which isn't the best, I am open to suggestion to improve the plotting process.
Finally you have to adjust x and y axis format and labels.

### Complete Code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.dates as md


df = pd.read_csv(r'data/data.csv')


def start(x):
    H, M, S = list(map(int, x['Start'].split(':')))
    Y, m, d = 2000, 1, 1
    if H > 12:
        return datetime(year = Y, month = m, day = d, hour = H, minute = M, second = S)
    else:
        return datetime(year = Y, month = m, day = d, hour = H, minute = M, second = S) + timedelta(days = 1)

def end(x):
    H, M, S = list(map(int, x['End'].split(':')))
    Y, m, d = 2000, 1, 1
    return datetime(year = Y, month = m, day = d, hour = H, minute = M, second = S) + timedelta(days = 1)


df['Start'] = df.apply(start, axis = 1)
df['End'] = df.apply(end, axis = 1)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d')


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    ax.plot([row['Date'], row['Date']], [row['Start'], row['End']], linewidth = 10, color = 'blue')

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.DayLocator(interval = 1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation = 90)


ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(md.HourLocator(interval = 1))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
ax.set_ylim(datetime(year = 2000, month = 1, day = 1, hour = 20, minute = 0, second = 0),
            datetime(year = 2000, month = 1, day = 2, hour = 12, minute = 0, second = 0))

plt.show()
```

[image]